# how to use `$class` in jenksinfile pipeline bash script

Tags: bash, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Team,
I am trying to create credential id using groovy script that has bash script. it gives me error. how can i escape it?

```
            steps {
                container('main') {
                    script {
                        withCredentials([[$class: 'VaultUsernamePasswordCredentialBinding', credentialsId: 'vaulted-jenkins-api-token' , passwordVariable: 'JENKINS_USER_TOKEN', usernameVariable: 'JENKINS_USERNAME']]) {
                            sh '''export JENKINS_CRUMB=$(curl -u "$JENKINS_USERNAME:$JENKINS_USER_TOKEN" -s --cookie-jar /tmp/cookies $JENKINS_URL'/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')'''
                            sh(script:"""#!/bin/bash
                                curl -X POST https://${JENKINS_USERNAME}:${JENKINS_USER_TOKEN}@${JENKINS_URL}/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials \
                                --data-urlencode 'json={
                                "credentials": {
                                    "scope": "GLOBAL",
                                    "id": "identification",
                                    "username": "manu",
                                    "password": "bar",
                                    "description": "linda1",
                                    "${class}": "com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl"
                                }
                                }'
                                echo "Creds link is ${credsLink}"
                            """)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 99: unexpected token: class @ line 99, column 39.
                                       "$class": "com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl"
                                         ^

1 error
```

Comment: These kinds of syntax issues can usually be avoided by cleaning up the code. Have you tried defining the credentials as a Groovy Map and then serializing to a JSON string? Have you tried using the HTTPRequest plugin? These changes would both assist with your definition.

Comment: i just figured out that i had to use double quotes intead of single quote and escape the `$class` with`\`. so am making progress. however, am getting 404 not sure what that implies. this script works locally fine.

Comment: you can escape the string like so `\${class}`

Answer (score 0):

has to use \ to escape it

```
            steps {
                container('main') {
                    script {
                        withCredentials([[$class: 'VaultUsernamePasswordCredentialBinding', credentialsId: 'vaulted-jenkins-api-token' , passwordVariable: 'JENKINS_USER_TOKEN', usernameVariable: 'JENKINS_USERNAME']]) {
                            sh '''export JENKINS_CRUMB=$(curl -u "$JENKINS_USERNAME:$JENKINS_USER_TOKEN" -s --cookie-jar /tmp/cookies $JENKINS_URL'/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')'''
                            sh(script:"""#!/bin/bash
                                curl -X POST https://${JENKINS_USERNAME}:${JENKINS_USER_TOKEN}@${JENKINS_URL}/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials \
                                --data-urlencode 'json={
                                "credentials": {
                                    "scope": "GLOBAL",
                                    "id": "identification",
                                    "username": "manu",
                                    "password": "bar",
                                    "description": "linda1",
                                    "\${class}": "com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl"
                                }
                                }'
                                echo "Creds link is ${credsLink}"
                            """)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```